# How can I move my SVN project from my local directory to another location?

Tags: ios, svn, cornerstone

I'm trying to move my SVN project from my local directory to another location on my MacBook Pro M1. I currently use the SVN application Cornerstone to manage my SVN repositories and files.
However, I'm not sure how to go about relocating my project. I need to ensure I move all of the necessary files and maintain version control during the migration process. I'm hoping there's a step-by-step procedure that I can follow to safely move my SVN project to its new destination without any issues. I'm also open to suggestions for alternative SVN applications or any tips for a smoother relocation process. I would appreciate any insights or guidance on this matter.

Comment: I’d the question is about SVN working copy then you can just move or drag and drop it in Finder or via Terminal. Then open it in Cornersone.

Comment: Is this about a *working copy* or about a repository? If the former, do as bahrep says. Or checkout a working copy in the new location.